# Exclude constraint across many tables?

Tags: postgresql, exclusion-constraint

Consider the following table:

```
todos:

 id | floor_start | floor_end
----+-------------+-------------
 1  | 10          | 20
 2  | 20          | 30
 3  | 30          | 40
 4  | 35          | 45
```

to prevent 2 elevators on the same floor I can go with:

```
EXCLUDE USING gist(int4range(start,end) with &&)
```

In this case 3 will conflict with 4.

However I do have a joining table:

```
occupations:

 todo_id | room_id
---------+----------
 3       | 1
 4       | 2
```

so (3) is done in `room_id = 1` and (4) is done in `room_id = 2` and they will not conflict.

1 & 2 do not have an entry in the joining table, so all rooms are occupied.

I understand that `exclude` will work only in the scope of the current table - how can I deal with it? Should I make redundant columns?

Adding `room_id` to `todos` is not an option because this is just a minimal example, and in the real life app I have more 0..N joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger that checks for the condition and throws an error if it isn't met.

But beware that such triggers have a race condition — two concurrent data modifications cannot see each other's effects. So you either have to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level or lock the affected rows in the trigger with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.